# Save string/EditText in memory android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a problem with save the value of string or editText in java android. When I redirect from FirstActivity to Second and return after it to First, I need that a String that i fill earlier stay in the place that I wrote it. (Like a cookies in js).

Comment: You could shared preferences for this process. First you need to save to value on shared preferences, then you could use that value from shared preferences after return to first activity.

Comment: and how to code it?

Comment: I add the code for the shared preferences process and then you need to use that code with your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use shared preferences for this process.

In that case, Best practise to create `SharedPreference` and for global usage, you need to create a global class like below:

```
public class PreferenceHelper {
private final SharedPreferences mPrefs;

public PreferenceHelperDemo(Context context) {
    mPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 -for private mode
}

private String PREF_Key= "Key";

public String getKey() { // To retrieve data
    String str = mPrefs.getString(PREF_Key, null);
    return str;
}

public void setKey(String pREF_Key) { // To store and edit Data
    Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    mEditor.putString(PREF_Key, pREF_Key);
    mEditor.commit();
}

public void clearData(string pREF_Key){ // To delete data
   editor.remove(pREF_Key); 
   editor.commit();
} 

}
```

Then you could use these functions with global class in your activity class to store, retrieve and delete the shared preference data.

Hope this will solve your problem!